# not printing if both statements are the same

Tags: python, if-statement, equals-operator

I'm trying to print `draw` if  players and computer choose the same variable, It can not printing if both statements are the same  at the moment it just ends after the computers choice and ignores the if statement

```
rock = '''
    _______
---'   ____)
      (_____)
      (_____)
      (____)
---.__(___)
'''

paper = '''
    _______
---'   ____)____
          ______)
          _______)
         _______)
---.__________)
'''

scissors = '''
    _______
---'   ____)____
          ______)
       __________)
      (____)
---.__(___)
'''

#Write your code below this line 

players_choice = input("What do you choose? Type 0 for Rock, 1 for Paper or 2 for Scissors. ")

if players_choice == "0":
  print(rock)
elif players_choice == "1":
   print(paper)
elif players_choice == "2":
  print(scissors)

import random

print("Computer chooses:")

computer_options = [rock, paper, scissors]

computer_choice = random.choice(computer_options)

print(computer_choice)

if computer_choice == players_choice:
  print("Draw")
```

Comment: Look at how you define `rock`. Do you really expect this to be equal to one of the strings "0", "1". or "2"?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are comparing the players_choice  which can be "0", "1" or "2" with computers choice that can be rock, paper or scissors,

That's why it can never be equal and can print Draw.

So simply you can set players_choice to something like below in your if, else blocks

```
if players_choice == "0":
    players_choice = rock
    print(rock)
elif players_choice == "1":
    players_choice = paper
    print(paper)
elif players_choice == "2":
    players_choice = scissors
    print(scissors)
```

So then this comparison will make more sense;

```
if computer_choice == players_choice:
  print("Draw")
```

Complete Updated Snippet:

```
rock = '''
    _______
---'   ____)
      (_____)
      (_____)
      (____)
---.__(___)
'''

paper = '''
    _______
---'   ____)____
          ______)
          _______)
         _______)
---.__________)
'''

scissors = '''
    _______
---'   ____)____
          ______)
       __________)
      (____)
---.__(___)
'''

players_choice = input("What do you choose? Type 0 for Rock, 1 for Paper or 2 for Scissors. ")

if players_choice == "0":
    players_choice = rock
    print(rock)
elif players_choice == "1":
    players_choice = paper
    print(paper)
elif players_choice == "2":
    players_choice = scissors
    print(scissors)

import random

print("Computer chooses:")

computer_options = [rock, paper, scissors]

computer_choice = random.choice(computer_options)

print(computer_choice)

if computer_choice == players_choice:
  print("Draw")
```

Comment: Why do you use `str(players_choice)` in the comparison? `players_choice` is a return value from a call to `input` and `input` always returns a string. Converting a string to a string seems ... strange.